# Angular + jQuery .on() doesn't work with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

jQuery `.on()` is not working with ng-repeat, when I fetch data by `$http()`.

It's working fine:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ['arrow-new', 'arrow-work', 'arrow-close']" class="arrow {{item}}">
</div>
```

**Events:**

```
$(".arrow").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
    //Ok
  } else {
  }
});
```

But when I load my array for iteration with `$http()` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in statused" class="arrow {{item}}">
</div>

$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/app/data/statuses.json' }).success(function (data) {
   $scope.statused = data;
});
```

my arrow is rendering fine, but events is not binding. I haven't error in debug console.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: delegates ! please use delegates !

Comment: `statuses` is defined in your JS, and `statuseD` is referred to in your markup

Comment: Sorry, when I reedit my code for stackoverflow, I done this markup)

Answer (score 2):

No need to use jQuery here, just use [ngMouseenter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter) and [ngMouseleave](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave) and then you can define the handlers in your controller:

markup (statused => statuses):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in statuses" class="arrow {{item}}" 
    ng-mouseenter="handleEvent()" ng-mouseleave="handleEvent()"></div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.handleEvent = function(){
    //add logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `statused` is undefined there is no any div.arrow on the page, so the `$(".arrow")` will be empty. You need to attach handler after `statused` is loaded and rendered, or use container and event delegation, or use ng-mouseenter directive.